# Increased amount of each row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question regarding fetch data in the form of table. i have a table with a single row now i just want amount increased on the basis on given logic.. 
like

```
1st row amount=1200, 
2nd row amount=1320(1200+120),
3rd row amount=1452(1320+132)
```

logic is 10% add with previous amount

My table is

```
Sno - Name- Amount
1  - A  -  1200
```

Now I want result like this..

```
Sno - Name- Amount

1  - A  -  1200
2  - A  -  1320
3  - A  -  1452
```

Can anybody help me i'm not find any logic for that

Comment: What RDBMS are you using sql-server or MySQL? Surely it can't be both `-)

Comment: I'm using sql server @Mureinik

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Adding demo data?
Because populating data like this is probably more performant in a program.

Comment: Sounds like you need a RUNNING TOTAL, you will need to use the OVER Clause to achieve this:- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: @user3016777, if you give us more info on what you need I can try to adapt my answer - or is it that you need to return more rows than my answer will?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has exactly the same limitation as WadimX's answer, but it'll do 100 rows. To produce your example output given your input table (which I'll refer to as `example`):

```
;WITH nums AS
   (SELECT 1 AS RowNum, Name, Amount
    FROM (SELECT Name, Amount FROM example) s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowNum + 1 As RowNum, Name, CAST(1.1*Amount AS INT) AS Amount
    FROM nums
    WHERE RowNum < 5) 
SELECT RowNum AS SNo, Name, Amount
FROM nums 
ORDER BY Name
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/524ae/1/0)

That returns 5 rows for every record in `example`, you can increase that count by changing the `RowNum < 5` to `100` or however many you want.

**Output**

```
SNo    Name     Amount
-----------------------
1      A        1200
2      A        1320
3      A        1452
...    ...      ...
```

Comment: what is 1.1 here?? and how it will calculate value?

Comment: The OP's logic is that each value is the previous value + 10%. Value is declared as 1200 to begin with, and then as itself + 10% during the recursion.

Comment: I managed to butcher the code for a bit during an edit there but its back working ;)

Comment: can i start it with second row?

Comment: Easiest way to do that would just be `SELECT 0 AS RowNum` initially and then have `WHERE RowNum > 0`

Comment: how i get a a particular column value to insert in another table

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to select the initial value from another table you'd so something like this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12412/0). If you want to insert some values from this query into another table you'd just change the final `SELECT ... FROM` to match your desired `INSERT`.

Comment: @user3016777, Are you sure? I have adapted to code for exactly your purpose [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc7a0/2/0) I have updated the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH COUNTER(RN) 
    AS 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) 
        FROM sys.objects
    ),
    A(RN, value) 
    AS 
    (
        SELECT CAST(1 as bigint),
               CAST(1200 as decimal(20, 0))
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT COUNTER.RN,
               CAST(A.value*1.1 as decimal(20, 0)) 
        FROM COUNTER JOIN A ON A.RN=COUNTER.RN-1
    )
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM A
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

This example selects first 1000 rows from sys.objects. You should replace **sys.objects** with your table name and **object_id** with primary/unique key column(s). Also you should change **TOP 1000** and **MAXRECURSION 1000**. Notice MAXRECURSION мау be between 0 and 32767, 0 - no limit.
Be aware of large tables, because it can cause arithmetic overflow of value.

Comment: CTE breaks at 100 recursivity level, you cannot have 1000 rows with this one. Change sys.objects with master..spt_values and object_id with name to check. BTW nice try :)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask for:

```
select sno, name, amount from table1
union select sno+1, name, amount*1.1 from table1
union select sno+2, name, amount*1.1*1.1 from table1
```

But it's not very flexible. E.g. if there are multiple rows you might get duplicate 'sno' numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Remodified answer to use cte instead:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (sno INT, name CHAR(1), amount INT)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 1, 'a', 1200

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  sno, name, amount
    FROM    @T
    WHERE sno = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sno+1, name, amount + amount / 10
    FROM cte
    WHERE sno+1 <= 100
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
```

Results:

```
sno name    amount
1   a   1200
2   a   1320
3   a   1452
4   a   1597
5   a   1756
6   a   1931
```